# Nor gate using photodiodes and transistors doesn't work correctly

Tags: transistors, logic-gates, photodiode

I'm creating a circuit for a robot to avoid obstacles. It is created without using any ICs. When the robot meets an obstacle the LED (at the right side of the transistors) should be off because of V_CE is 0.7V and voltage barrier across the led is 1.5V.

My problem is when the robot meets an obstacle it just reduces the light intensity of LED. It means that my logic gate doesn't work correctly. What is wrong with my circuit?

I need to give the output into the opamp.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: What voltage do you measure across the LED itself?  By what means of measurement?  Could it be pulsing in a way a meter does not detect? For that matter open environment optical sensors typically must use pulsed illumination and pulse detectors to gain immunity from other sources of light.

Comment: You need to learn the dangers of asking a bunch of seasoned engineers "what is wrong with my circuit"!

Comment: `without using any ICs` ... what is the opamp then?

Comment: Do some measurements, think about he resulst... Hint: for what the resistors have as low values?????? BTW: usage of OP-AMP for driving relay coil is slightly... Ok, think on this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've drawn your original receiver stage on the left, and an improved one on the right.

A photodiode generates current proportional to the light impinging on it, plus a bit of leakage current (called "dark current" in the datasheet).  A transistor will pretty much amplify any base current -- so the circuit on the left will *always* have some collector current, and in the case of a photodiode that always has some light on it, it will be difficult to control the on/off switch point.

In the circuit on the right, R5 will consume some of the current from D2.  This will hold the base voltage of Q2 down.  Then you can select R5 such that the base voltage of the transistor hits 0.6V at roughly the light level you want to sense.  With carefully controlled lighting, this may be enough to make things work for you.

Note that I suggest that if you use this circuit, you make R5 adjustable -- I'd suggest an audio taper pot, because those are roughly logarithmic (see my comment to this answer for my reason).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSUCZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is outside of your question, but: it's almost impossible to realize just how much variation in ambient light that humans can put up with without even noticing.  Like just about every other sensory experience, humans tend to see light intensities logarithmically.  Bright sunlight may be 100 times brighter than a comfortably lit room.  We just accommodate to that without noticing, while your circuit will either be swamped with light outside, or totally insensitive inside.

Comment: Tim , you could have added log scale with diode +R feedback.. Sharp had an amazing 5mm Light sensor with over 5 decades , but even Vishay couldn't sell enough to keep them in production. Chromatic CIE filter et al.

Answer (score 0):

> "My problem is when the robot meets an obstacle it just reduces the light intensity of LED".

This suggests your logic gate works as you intended. Judging LED current by eye, versus judging current threshold with the opamp suggests the fault lies with the opamp.

Using an opamp to detect an obstacle-in-path is not a good idea. This is a job for a comparator. Since many comparators are open-collector, the relay-driver output might be re-arranged so that the relay coil goes to the DC supply.
Ensure that the negative end of *both DC supplies* must be connected together at the comparator's negative supply pin. **BAT1** supplies motor current and relay current, while **+DC supply** is for the LED and logic gate and comparator. The logic circuitry that drives R3, LED D1 is not shown.

You should also include a clear threshold voltage to compare against (instead of 0V in the OP). When LED current is below threshold, the relay is not activated. In the diagram below, R2 sets the threshold voltage, deciding when an object is encountered:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6BvGb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the simple logic in OP is commendable (simplicity is always a good first approach) it has faults. Ambient light varies, and can be falsely detected as an obstacle....but that's another matter.